# Use SET from SELECT statement doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why can I not set variable to select query result? I am receiving an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'tbl'

Code:

```
DECLARE @AgentNumber INT = 2428
DECLARE @Node HIERARCHYID

SET @Node =  -- this is throwing me syntax error
    (SELECT Node 
     FROM CM.ERGO_HIERARCHY
     WHERE AgentNumber = @AgentNumber) tbl
```

I know that below code works, but why I can not simply use SET ?

```
SELECT @Node = Node    -- that works
FROM
    (SELECT Node 
     FROM CM.ERGO_HIERARCHY
     WHERE AgentNumber = @AgentNumber) tbl
```

Comment: Here you cannot use ALIAS  as tbl for INNER QUERY when you are assigning value to a VARIABLE. Just remove the tbl and check.

Comment: Just a guess, but why do you need an alias for the sub-select? Try removing tbl.

Comment: It works. Basically that means when I remove alias for subquery that this is  the result as variable ? Using alias means like I am using subquery as datatable ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use alias with SET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
SET @Node = 
(
SELECT TOP 1 Node 
FROM CM.ERGO_HIERARCHY
WHERE AgentNumber = @AgentNumber
)
```